# How do I sum cost from subtable

Tags: ms-access

I was wondering how I would go about summing the costs of an individual record with all related records from a subtable into a "total Cost" column, see picture

[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: Show us your tables, in design view and the relationship between them.

Comment: Build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs.